# Graph API search returns different results than fb search

Tags: facebook-graph-api, restfb

I login in facebook with my user and I get an access token from api explorer.

If i search  coca-cola in the facebook search box on the normal wall page i get the (official) coca cola page as first result, which has 40 million fans.

If i search with restfb with the graph api, using my access token , that page isn't found in the first 550+ results :  [Fb explorer query](http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Coca-Cola&fields=name,likes,category,&type=page&format=json)

(I noticed it's the same in fb: if you search in the search bar without pressing enter, that page is the first, if you then click on get all results, that page isn't in the results.)

Why? 
*Is there a way to get ALL the results like in the search box?* 
*Or at least to get the most "liked" first?*

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately the Graph API is kinda a "stripped down version" of Facebook's data and functionality. The best you can do is to paginate where you can, and also explore both FQL as well as the newer Graph API objects to pull data from.